# Magento 2 shop by price is not showing on sub category pages

Tags: magento2, category, price, layered-navigation, filter

Magento 2.3.5-p2

shop by price is not showing on the subcategory page, it is showing on category pages
[image]

[image]

Comment: How many product you have on the subcategory page and those all are from different price range or not?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya total 9 products are showing and their price is also different

Comment: @DhirenVasoya i checked again and change product price now the shop by price showing

Comment: ok your issues is resolve now, right?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya yes